# Bootstrap collapse example broken in Chrome

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason the collapse example from the bootstrap website is broken in Chrome.  I pasted this markup right into my page, and the simple accordion works fine in FireFox, but breaks in Chrome.  The way in which it breaks in Chrome is that I can toggle between the two panes *once*, and then no further collapsing works at all.

I'm using the latest version of bootstrap.

The code is below, which is a straight paste from the bootstrap site.

I've read that some jQuery plugins that improperly use $.transition can cause issues like this.  Are there any that cause issues with only Chrome?

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you reported this as an issue on their github page?

Comment: @ajk - no, I narrowed it down to a problem with prototype (which we're in the process of ditching).  I'm sure they have no interest in fixing this, nor should they.

Comment: I had the same problem when using jQuery 1.7. After I updated to jQuery 1.8.3, the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code with you HTML:

```
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css"></link>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#accordion2").collapse()​;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, that's still broken in Chrome.  It looks like there some terrible conflict somewhere

Comment: For identifications errors may be use Opera dragonfly -> errors -> jawascript or Chrome console's

Comment: Doesn't look to be any errors - problem seems related to the fact that the transition state is never getting reset in chrome (and only chrome)

Comment: Narrowed this down to some old POS prototype utilities (which we're in the process of killing) being the problem.  +1 for your time :)